# Can't import django-tenants even I installed

Tags: django

I am going to use django-tenants but I couldn't import it even I installed.

```
from django_tenants.models import DomainMixin
from django_tenants.utils import get_public_schema_name, schema_context
```

Import "django_tenants.models" could not be resolved.
I can see this error.

Comment: Is that an actual error or is that just your IDE speaking? The actual error would have looked like "ModuleNotFoundError: ...", please actually run your code and test (If you get an error then you have installed the module in the wrong venv, etc, if you don't your IDE isn't using the correct venv).

Comment: Yes, sure. It is from the IDE.